# VBA SpecialCells Property not found in Range Object

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, range

I have an issue with the SpecialCells property of the Range Object while accessing an Excel Worksheet from a Word Document. Simply, the SpecialCells property is not found while I try to select the filtered cells from the Worksheet. I seem to be accessing the Worksheet and Range objects just fine. I have thought of using the AutoFilter Object directly from the Worksheet but the current approach seems so much easier. Help?

```
Sub FillDBSchedules(XLWorkbook As Object)

Dim i As Integer
Dim CurrentStructureName As String
Dim RelevantRange As Object
Dim FirstTable As Object
Dim NewRow As Object

CurrentStructureName = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Structure_Name").Value
Set FirstTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

With XLWorkbook.Worksheets("DB Schedules")
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CurrentStructureName
        Set RelevantRange = .SpecialCells(Type:=.xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    For i = 1 To RelevantRange.Rows.Count
        Set NewRow = FirstTable.Rows.Add
        NewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = i
    Next i
    'Reset filter to select all
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Please replace `Type:=.xlCellTypeVisible` with 12. To become `Set RelevantRange = .SpecialCells(12)`. `xlCellTypeVisible` is not a sheet property, so the dot in front of it does not help. It is an Excel object constant. Or declare it `Const xlCellTypeVisible As Long = 12`, and use it like in Excel...

Comment: Thanks, this has worked. But why does it not work with the name of the constant? I have used other constant names in the script (eg. wdCharacter) and they have worked just fine. Is it because I am not within Excel?

Comment: Like I said, this is **Excel object constant**... VBA Word does not know about it. You can use it as in Excel if you declare it as I suggested above.

Comment: `wdCharacter` is a constant in word library, if you want constants/enum that are available in excel library then add it in your reference (early-binding), else you have to provide the numerical value or declare the constant manually as advised by FaneDuru

Comment: You can find all Excel constants [here](http://www.smarterdatacollection.com/Blog/?p=374)...